# How do you compare two arrays, and find out how many of the values are alike?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a bit of an issue finding out how i compare two arrays in JavaScript with a function. Not just comparing them but also finding out how many of the values are alike.

I know how to do it with an unusually big if / else if statement, but this makes the code rubbish and hard to read.

For example:

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var array2 = [3,4,5,6,7];
```

In this case 3, 4 and 5 would be values represented in both arrays, but what is a good way to compare the two and find this out via a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to count how many of are `include()`d in the other:

```js
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var array2 = [3,4,5,6,7];

let count = array1.reduce((count, item) => count + (array2.includes(item) ? 1 : 0), 0)
console.log(count)
```

If it's possible that `array1` has duplicates and you only want to count them once. You can use Sets:

```js
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,5];
var array2 = [3,4,5,6,7];

let s2 = new Set(array2)

let count = [...new Set(array1)].reduce((count, item) => s2.has(item) ? count + 1 : count, 0)

// still 3
console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here use filter.

```js
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var array2 = [3,4,5,6,7];

var commonArray = array1.filter(element => array2.includes(element));

console.log(commonArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
array1.reduce((accum, n) => {
    const accumulator = [...accum];
    if(array2.includes(n))
        accumulator.push(n)
    return accumulator;
},[])
```